# How to store 2 variables and compare them

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to accept user input for two people's hourly wage and the amount of hours of overtime they work per year.

using an algorithm I have researched, the program will tell both people the amount of money they make per year and the amount of taxes they pay, which is based on the amount that they make.

This is all fine and dandy. However, what I am now trying to do is to add a line at the end of the program which states who is paying more taxes. This would be accomplished with the method `whoPaysMoreTaxes`, but I have no idea what to include in that method. I know I would need a simple if/ else if/ else statement to get the job done, but I do not know how I would go about storing the taxes of person 1 and the taxes of person 2 and compare them. The output should be as follows I believe. The numbers 22, 100, 58, and 260 are user input:

```
Person 1's hourly wage: 22
Person 1's overtime hours for the year: 100
You will make $45540 this year
And you will pay $9108 in taxes
Person 2's hourly wage: 58
Person 2's overtime hours for the year: 260
You will make $133980 this year
And you will pay $40194 in taxes.
Person 2 is paying more taxes.
```

The issue I am having is finding a way to produce that final line that says who is paying more taxes.

```
public class conditionalsAndReturn
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
       taxes(console, 1);
       taxes(console, 2);
   }
   public static void taxes(Scanner console, int personNum)
   {
      System.out.print("Person " + personNum + "'s hourly wage: ");
      int wage = console.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Person " + personNum + "'s overtime hours for the year: ");
      double totalOvertimeHours = console.nextInt();        
      int salary = annualSalary(wage, totalOvertimeHours);
      System.out.println("You will make $" + salary + " this year");
      System.out.println("And you will pay $" + taxation(salary) + " in taxes");
      System.out.println();   
   }

   public static int annualSalary(int wage, double totalOvertimeHours)
   {
      double workHoursPerWeek = 40 + totalOvertimeHours / 48;
      return (int)(weeklyPay(wage, workHoursPerWeek) * 48); 
    } 

   public static double weeklyPay(int wage, double workHoursPerWeek)
   {
       if (workHoursPerWeek > 40)
       {  
           return (wage * 40) + ((wage + wage / 2.0) * (workHoursPerWeek - 40));    
       }
       else
       {
          return wage * workHoursPerWeek;  
       }
    } 

   public static int taxation(int salary)
   {
       if (salary < 20000)
       {
           return 0;
       }
       else if (salary > 100000)
       {
           return salary * 3 / 10; 
       }
       else
       {
           return salary * 2 / 10;
       }
   }

  public static String whoPaysMoreTaxes(
}
```

Comment: Start by making `taxes` return a result, instead of being `void`.

Comment: When you call `taxation(salary)`, save the return of that function in a variable. Then, return that value from your `taxes` function, and save the return value every time you call `taxes` into separate variables. Then you can compare.

Comment: It is better to use a `double` than `int` when dealing with monetary values

Comment: @cricket_007 Actually, it's better to use `BigDecimal` than either.  However, if you know you will be dealing only with integer values (reasonable since this is about taxes and the IRS lets you round everything to whole dollar amounts when filing), and you'll never need to divide monetary amounts, using `int` is reasonable.

Comment: @ajb Said better, not "best" :)

Answer (score 1):

The OOP conform coding would be, to have a class person (or better employee), with the fields: personNum, one or more of the three wage/salary variables, taxation. Add name and such if needed.

Now you can use instances of those class to store the accumulated data, and compare the objects with a compareTo.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to follow true Object Oriented programming principles, then you might create a separate class which represents a Person object (or consider a nested class). Then each Person instance could have the attributes:

- hourly_wage
- overtime_hours
- income
- taxes_owed

You would then want to create as many People classes as you need, using the class instances to store data. You could then modify your method header to be:

```
public Person who_payes_more_taxes(Person p1, Person p2): { ... }
```

Inside the method you would need to decide how to compare taxes, but most likely it will look something like:

```
if (p1.taxes_owed > p2.taxes_owed) { return p1 }
```

Comment: Well, Java isn't Python, so `camelCase` is preffered

Comment: You're completely correct. Please forgive my sloppiness; it's late and i've been coding too much Python recently. Haha.

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely on the right track.  I would use more variables to simplify comparing the taxes:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConditionalsAndReturn
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int personOneWage;
        int personOneOvertime;
        double personOnePayBeforeTax;
        double personOneTaxes;
        double personOneNetIncome;

        int personTwoWage;
        int personTwoOvertime;
        double personTwoPayBeforeTax;
        double personTwoTaxes;
        double personTwoNetIncome;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Person 1's hourly wage: ");
        personOneWage = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Person 1's overtime hours for the year: ");
        personOneOvertime = scan.nextInt();
        personOnePayBeforeTax = (40 * personOneWage) + (personOneOvertime * personOneWage * 1.5);
        personOneTaxes = taxes(personOnePayBeforeTax);
        personOneNetIncome = personOnePayBeforeTax - personOneTaxes;
        System.out.println("You will make $" + personOneNetIncome + " this year");
        System.out.println("And you will pay $" + personOneTaxes + " in taxes");

        System.out.print("Person 2's hourly wage: ");
        personTwoWage = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Person 2's overtime hours for the year: ");
        personTwoOvertime = scan.nextInt();
        personTwoPayBeforeTax = (40 * personTwoWage) + (personTwoOvertime * personTwoWage * 1.5);
        personTwoTaxes = taxes(personTwoPayBeforeTax);
        personTwoNetIncome = personTwoPayBeforeTax - personTwoTaxes;
        System.out.println("You will make $" + personTwoNetIncome + " this year");
        System.out.println("And you will pay $" + personTwoTaxes + " in taxes");

        if (personOneTaxes > personTwoTaxes)
        {
            System.out.println("Person 1 is paying more in taxes.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Person 2 is paying more in taxes.");
        }

        scan.close();
    }

    private static double taxes(double payBeforeTax)
    {
        if (payBeforeTax < 20000)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (payBeforeTax > 100000)
        {
            return payBeforeTax * 3 / 10;
        }
        else
        {
            return payBeforeTax * 2 / 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding `Person` classes would be better, though

Comment: I agree, adding a Person class would make this easier.  However, I think the OP is not quite at the level of creating their own objects quite yet.

Comment: Agreed, though, the do seem to be at a level of not putting almost everything in the main method.